# Error importing sass files

Tags: nativescript

I am having an issue trying to import SCSS files in my Nativescript app. I am adding these lines to add my default theme styles in my app, the lines are added in the `app.android.scss` and `app.ios.scss`:

```
@import '~/assets/skin';
@import '~/assets/list';
```

The files are inside `app/assets` folder and their real names are: `_skin.scss` and `_list.scss`.

The problem is when I try to use Nativescript Sidekick and build for iOS in the cloud it gives me this error:

```
Found peer node-sass
[17-10-25 13:55:16.820] (Info) Error: It's not clear which file to import for '@import \"assets/skin\"'.
[17-10-25 13:55:16.822] (Info) Candidates:
[17-10-25 13:55:16.823] (Info) assets/_skin.scss
[17-10-25 13:55:16.825] (Info) assets/skin.css
```

But building the app for android locally it works.

Any suggestion?

Thanks!

Comment: Same thing just happened to me out of the blue. Also building for iOS.
The last thing I did before this happened is installing tns-platform-declaraions. It happens on my local machine build, using Drawer Navigation template from Sidekick.